# Modal box keeps disappearing even after I have removed other bootstrap.min.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to make my modal box stop disappearing, but nothing I have done is working. I have even used the solution of some of the threads I have seen online, but they are not working. How can I keep it from disappearing?

This is my code:

```
<html>

    <head>

    <title> Test Slides </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <style type="text/css">


   .carousel-control {
    padding-top:10%;
    width:5%;
    }
    /* Video icon overlay on image */
    .videos img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
   }
   a.video {
   float: left;
  position: relative;
}
a.video span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: url("images/lightbox-play.png") no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: 15%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  a.video span {
    background-size: 400%;
  }
}
/* gutter spaces */
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:first-child),
.row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:last-child) {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
}

.row.no-gutter {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
     /* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Modal Video*/
.modal iframe {

   position: absolute;
   left: 20%;
   top: 10%; 

}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)}
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

    </style>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-12">
         <h1>Nerdic Consult</h1>

            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

                <!-- Carousel items -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="row no-gutter">
                            <div id="myImg1" class="col-sm-3 videos"><a href="" class="video"><span></span><img src="images/image 1.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 videos"><a href="" class="video"><span></span><img src="images/image 2.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 videos"><a href="" class="video"><span></span><img src="images/image 3.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 videos"><a href="" class="video"><span></span><img src="images/image 4.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="row no-gutter">
                            <div class="col-sm-3 videos"><a href="" class="video"><span></span><img src="images/image 5.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 videos"><a href="" class="video"><span></span><img src="images/image 6.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 videos"><a href="" class="video"><span></span><img src="images/image 7.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3 videos"><a href="" class="video"><span></span><img src="images/image 8.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--/row-->
                    </div>
                    <!--/item-->
                </div>
                <!--/carousel-inner--> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><img src="images/lightbox-prev.png"/></a>

                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><img src="images/lightbox-next.png"/></a>
            </div>
            <!--/myCarousel-->

            <!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal1').style.display='none'">&times;</span>

  <!-- Modal Content (The Video) -->
  <iframe width="60%" height="60%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AhTbZTLkIIs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

</div>
    </div>


</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 10000
    })

    $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
        //alert("slid");
    });


});

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal1');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg1');
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Given that you have jQuery loaded (since it's a dependency for Bootstrap), why are you using getElementById, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much, no need to bother. I discovered it was the `href` in the anchor tag that was responsible. I deleted the `href=""` in the anchor tag and the modal box stayed.

Comment: Welcome on the site - thank you for your answering your question.